# Dismiss ViewController opened from SideMenu

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, dismiss

I have small app with 5 screens that are embedded in Navigation stack and I can't dismiss `UIViewController`

I'm using [SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) in my project to present last `UIViewController` from it, here's a code configuration of side menu:

```
SideMenuManager.default.menuPushStyle = .replace
SideMenuManager.default.menuPresentMode = .menuSlideIn
```

And the way how I'm presenting VC:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "menuToSavedQuotes" {
        _ = segue.destination as? SavedQuotesViewController
    }
}
```

And then: `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "menuToSavedQuotes", sender: self)`

It works just fine, but then when I call action for dismissing - this doesn't work. I'm not using nav bar in my app, that's why I created button and tried to dismiss it but failed.

What I tried is:

`self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

But none of this worked. What I have right now and still not working is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    output?.viewIsReady()
    setupNavigationStack()
}

@IBAction func didPressClose(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Here")
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    //self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func setupNavigationStack() {
    if let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? StartingPageViewController {
        let navigation = root.childViewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController

        let vc1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartingPage")
        let vc2 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartTrial")
        let vc3 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScheduleNotifications")
        let vc4 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AllQuotes")
        let vc5 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SavedQuotes")

        navigation.setViewControllers([vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4, vc5], animated: true)
    }
}
```

As a temporary solution my close button just opens previous `UIViewController` but this is not a good practice.

Would be grateful for any help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for a while I still could not locate source of my issue so I stayed with workaround:

Close button just opens previous `UIViewController` but this is not a good practice.

In my case application has only 3 screens and it's fine, but if to talk about bigger apps such solution is not recommended.